# Make static site from wordpress site using bash

Tags: bash, wget, wordpress, htaccess

I have tried a few other scripts that can make a static version of a wordpress site but none of them are designed for bulk sites and I haven't found any that will just serve a static version while keeping the original. Here was my attempt but now I'm getting a bash error `line 10: syntax error near unexpected token ('`

Here's my current code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for DOMAIN in "$@"
do
  cd /var/www/$DOMAIN/web/
  wget -m -r -p -N -F -E http://www.$DOMAIN
  mv www.$DOMAIN static-site
  mkdir _wordpress-site
  mv !(error|stats|_wordpress-site|static-site) _wordpress-site
  mv .htaccess _wordpress-site
  echo '
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ static-site/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
   ' > .htaccess
done
```

if I escape the line with a parentheses like: `mv !\(error|stats|_wordpress-site|static-site\) _wordpress-site` I get 3 command not found errors

I have also tried escaping like: `mv '!(error|stats|_wordpress-site|static-site) _wordpress-site'` which gives me `mv: missing destination file operand after ‘!(error|stats|_wordpress-site|static-site) _wordpress-site’`